# Interpreting grunt command line option as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

As part of a build process, we run a Grunt task like this:

```
grunt release -r 3.9
```

The release number passed with the `-r` option is used to tag various parts of the release.

The trouble arises with releases that end in a zero -- e.g. 3.10. Grunt treats this as a number, drops the trailing zero and thinks that this is release 3.1.

Here's a simple Gruntfile which demonstrates the problem:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'Release preparation', function () {
    var rel = grunt.option("r").toString();

    grunt.log.writeln("Release data type:" + typeof rel);
    grunt.log.writeln("release (" + rel + ")");
  });
};
```

Here's what you get:

```
$ grunt -r 3.10
Running "default" task
Release data type:string
release (3.1)

Done, without errors.
```

The `toString()` converts it to a string appropriately, but the damage has already been done. The trailing zero is gone.

Any way around this?

Comment: Open an issue on this on Grunt's github: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/894

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems this behavior is by design, as grunt-cli uses [nopt](https://github.com/isaacs/nopt) module to do its command-line parsing. See the code [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/master/lib/cli.js), the key line being:

```
return nopt(exports.known, exports.aliases, process.argv, 2);
```

This is what [nopt has to say about types](https://github.com/isaacs/nopt#types) (emphasis mine):

> When parsing unknown fields, "true", "false", and "null" will be interpreted as their JavaScript equivalents, and **numeric values will be interpreted as a number.**

A couple workarounds might be:

1. Use something like `grunt release -r "v3.10"` on the command line and strip off the "v" in your grunt code
2. Read `process.argv` again in your grunt code and pass it into the option parser of your choosing

Comment: have to add 'v' and then strip it out